# How to check in runtime if .NET Core app is started via dotnet cli

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a test runner app which runs different tester apps.
Depending on the case if the runner app is started via `dotnet` CLI command (e.g. `>dotnet runner.dll -t tester1`) or via simple running of the published `.exe` file (e.g. `>runner.exe -t tester1`), I want to build different paths to the tester apps executable files.

How it's better to check this?

That's how I'll use it (it's a POC app, I need only that 2 cases here):

```
public TesterProcess(bool runViaDotnetCli)
{
    TesterInfo = new T();
    if (runViaDotnetCli)
    {
        Process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "dotnet",
                // TesterInfo.ExecutableFileName is something like "tester1.dll" here
                ArgumentList = {TesterInfo.ExecutableFileName, "--data", "something"},
                UseShellExecute = false, CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };
    }
    else
    {
        Process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                // TesterInfo.ExecutableFileName is something like "tester1.exe" here
                FileName = TesterInfo.ExecutableFileName,
                ArgumentList = {"--data", "something"},
                UseShellExecute = false, CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() could be helpful in this case.

Comment: I am curious why you would want to do that. Can you give us an example where having two different code paths for handling invocations differently would be useful?

Comment: @DanielFuchs, unfortunately, it's not. It returns exactly the running app assembly when I call `>dotnet runner.dll`.

Comment: @omajid added the sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for this would be to use [`Process.GetCurrentProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess?view=netcore-2.2) to the get the current process and then use its [`ProcessName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processname?view=netcore-2.2) property:

```
if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "dotnet")
{
    ...
}
```